# how to invoke a new activity the moment the user enter exactly 4 digits of code into an editText box

Tags: java, android

I would like to invoke a new activity the moment the user enter exactly 4 digits of code into an editText box.

how can i catch the exact moment the user enter the 4 and last digit and immediately invoke an action that checks if the code is valid.

Thanks,

Gil.

Comment: It obviously depends on specific circumstances, but this _might_ be annoying for the user if they've no opportunity to correct things if they've realised they hit the wrong number for the last digit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Text Watcher

```
    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //Start your activity
            if (s.length()==4)
                startactivity(new Intent(CallingActivity.this,CalledActivity.class));
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks! that was very helpful :) it can be nice if you vote for my question and then i could mark this answer as correct :)

Comment: @Gil4x6uu it's really poor taste to ask for upvotes and especially to hold an accept hostage for an upvote

Comment: @codeMagic It wasn't the idea, the accept came before the upvote request. But I will take into consideration the next time

Answer (score 0):

Please use textwatche class in android

Please check this link [click here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
   if(count == 4)
       {
           startactivity(new intent(...));
       }
});
//...
```

hope this can help

Answer (score 0):

Use [addTextChangedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener(android.text.TextWatcher))

```
EditText yourEdittext = new EditText(this)
yourEdittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
                if (s.toString().length() == 4 || count==4) {
                    //start your activity
                } 
           ....................
           ....................
           ....................
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code:

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
                if (count==4) {
                    //Start your new Activity from here
                } 
            }
    }
```